# How to find all `action()` in code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, search

I made an extension method for `Action` and I'd like to replace all occurrences of `action()` with `action.SafeInvoke()` in the code. But the problem is that `action` is just an example var name, and in reality they are all different. Searching by `()` will obviously produce terrible results. Searching by `Action` and looking up every individual var's references in code and finding direct invocation among that is kind of slow.

Is it possible to somehow find all occurrences of `Action` invocation by `()` operator when the variable names are unknown?

Comment: Rename/Remove the original and rebuild. The error list should now list every call you need to update.

Comment: @asawyer you mean the whole `Action` class? It's built in, I'm not sure it can be done. And besides it will be basically the same as looking up each occurrence of `Action` in code.

Comment: Oh I read that as wanting to change all calls to a method to your new extension method.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you have instances of type `Action` like:

```
Action foo = ...
Action bar = ...
```

And then you have in the code:

```
foo();
bar();
```

You want something that will change `foo()` to `foo.SafeInvoke()` and `bar()` to `bar.SafeInvoke()`.

There's nothing in Visual Studio that will do this for you automatically, and writing something to do it would be non-trivial. You'd spend a whole lot more time on that extension than you would by making the changes manually.

You can use Visual Studio's "Find usages" functionality to find every place that `Action` is used. That will at least help you locate where you need to make the changes.

I'd be interested to know, what your `SafeInvoke` does. If all it does is a null check, you might want to consider if it's really necessary.

Comment: Basically yes, it does a null check and prints to console once if it was null.